# ExtractMpegFramesTest example doesn't work on API23 Devices

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I tried to run [this bigflake example](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt) on some android devices.

I tried it on Galaxy S3, S4 and S7.

For Galaxy S3 everything works fine. I've taken the first frame and this is what I've got:
[image]

And then I tried to run the same code on Galaxy S6 and S7, but then I received a strange image for the same video [image]

Do someone(fadden lol) know what could cause this problem?